# Collection of short stories published before 1988: disappearing children in a small town, woman dreaming her husband is a snake

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone help me remember the author of a collection of short stories I read in high school? It was probably classified as sci-fi.

One story was about a town where people kept disappearing. Sometimes if kids disappeared they were found later in a different part of town. People realized after investigating that all of them had been eating when they were "fished out" and that the food packages had tiny errors (like fishing lures) and the kids were "thrown back" like we throw back under size fish.

Another story had a woman who kept having vivid dreams husband was turning into a snake. She awakens over and over shaken, upset and feeling awful about thinking of her husband like that,  and her husband settles her back to sleep. Then at the end of the story he pulls his pajama tie slowly out and runs it down her body like a snake- making her have the dream that's making her crazy.

Comment: The first story is "The Fishing Season" by Robert Sheckley. The second is also familiar but the author and title don't come to mind.

Comment: it might help if you told us when "high school" was :)

Comment: The other story is "Fear in the Night", also by Sheckley. Both are in his 1984 collection *Is That What People Do?* I was about to post this as an answer but Michael Edenfield beat me to it.

Answer (score 11):

Both of these are stories by [Robert Sheckley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?818), which are found in various collections of his short stories. There is a [five-volume set](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/196265.The_Collected_Short_Fiction_of_Robert_Sheckley_5_Volume_set) of all of his short stories, though I cannot find anywhere that sells it online. You can also find them in various other smaller combinations.

The first of your stories is called ["Fishing Season"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58554), and is found in [*The People Trap*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K627TNI).

The second is ["Fear in the Night"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58553), which is found in [*Pilgrimage to Earth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K627SNE).

Both of them were also put into the larger collection [*Is That What People Do?*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K627USM).